# When writing a custom iterator, how can I avoid the compiler generating a Reset() method that throws an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, iterator

I have coded a custom iterator as a workaround to a complex COM Interop issue. The iterator is about as simple as it gets:

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
        yield return DriveRates.driveSidereal;
        yield return DriveRates.driveKing;
        yield return DriveRates.driveLunar;
        yield return DriveRates.driveSolar;
        }
```

`DriveRates` is an enum.

My understanding is that the compiler is supposed to turn this into a state machine, and it does, but when a client app uses the code, I get this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at TiGra.Astronomy.AWRDriveSystem.TrackingRates.d__0.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumVariantViewOfEnumerator.Reset()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.Reset()
[...client app]
```

Looking at the compiler generated code in dotPeek, here's the generated Reset() method.

```
  [DebuggerHidden]
  void IEnumerator.Reset()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }
```

Well, I guess that explains the exception, but... WWWHHHYYYYY? Surely its not impossible in this situation for Reset to simply reset the state machine. Is there any way I can make the compiler generate a Reset() method that doesn't throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't. The assumption that the state machine can be reset does hold for your simple case, but be aware you can write iterators with *side effects*, and the compiler cannot assume the state machine is *pure* in the general case. So the safe bet is to simply disallow the `Reset` function (which, by the way, is *very* rarely used at all, to the point I think it's more of a design mistake than an useful feature).

The simplest workaround for your code is...

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new[] {
        DriveRates.driveSidereal,
        DriveRates.driveKing,
        DriveRates.driveLunar,
        DriveRates.driveSolar
    }.GetEnumerator();
}
```

I'm assuming the values in the `DriveRates` don't change during the enumeration, in which case the code wouldn't yield the same results: this version is *eager*.

Comment: Ah. Did I mention it was a complex COM Interop issue? The client app chokes on the iterator supplied by System.Array, hence me writing a custom iterator for an array ;-) Actually what happens is that something doesn't marshal properly and the client app gets a NullReferenceException when it tries to do a foreach() over the IEnumerable. I will try this approach though, just in case it works. Thanks for the suggestions, I appreciate it.

Comment: I sense you've been trapped by the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271659) here. Try to post another question about your COM issue, that may end up being more useful to your case.

Comment: Lucas, I see what you mean, and you are not wrong. The actual question could well take another seven and a half million years, though! But seriously, I will see if I can come up with a suitable way of phrasing the question.